# Nested Foreaches for Weekly Data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a list where customers can submit data weekly. I want to cycle through the weeks in a month (i.e. week 1, week 2...) and either show a value if it exists or show a select dropdown if not.

My problem is that I cant quite get the loops right. The below doesn't work as it outputs the data far too many times and i know the loops are in an incorrect order.

```
@if($customer->pay_schedule == 'weekly')
    @foreach($weeks as $week)
        @foreach($customer->payment as $payment)
            @if($week['week_start'] == $payment->pay_period_start & $week['week_end'] == $payment->pay_period_end)
                <div class="medium-3 columns">
                    Week {{ $loop->iteration }}

                @foreach($statuses as $status)
                    @if($payment->pay_status == $status->id)
                        {{ $status->status }}
                    @endif
                @endforeach
                </div>
            @else
                <div class="medium-3 columns">
                    Week {{ $loop->iteration }}

                <select name="pay_status[]" class="form-control">
                    @foreach($statuses as $status)
                        <option value="{{ $status->id }}"> {{ $status->status }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                </div>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endif
```

`$customer->payment` returns a collection of payments for that customer. So sometimes there is 4 weeks worth of data which is fine for the month.

But sometimes there is for example 3 weeks worth of data with week 4 missing which is the week where I would want a select to show so the data could be the entered.

Another example is there could be no data entered so a select would be needed for all 4 weeks of the month.

**$weeks data**

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "week_start" => Carbon {#239 ▼
      +"date": "2017-05-01 00:00:00.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Europe/London"
    }
    "week_end" => Carbon {#255 ▼
      +"date": "2017-05-08 00:00:00.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Europe/London"
    }
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "week_start" => Carbon {#256 ▼
      +"date": "2017-05-08 00:00:00.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Europe/London"
    }
    "week_end" => Carbon {#254 ▼
      +"date": "2017-05-15 00:00:00.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Europe/London"
    }
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "week_start" => Carbon {#247 ▼
      +"date": "2017-05-15 00:00:00.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Europe/London"
    }
    "week_end" => Carbon {#295 ▼
      +"date": "2017-05-22 00:00:00.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Europe/London"
    }
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "week_start" => Carbon {#271 ▼
      +"date": "2017-05-22 00:00:00.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Europe/London"
    }
    "week_end" => Carbon {#293 ▼
      +"date": "2017-05-29 00:00:00.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Europe/London"
    }
  ]
  4 => array:2 [▼
    "week_start" => Carbon {#291 ▼
      +"date": "2017-05-29 00:00:00.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Europe/London"
    }
    "week_end" => Carbon {#290 ▼
      +"date": "2017-06-05 00:00:00.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Europe/London"
    }
  ]
]
```

**$customer->payment data**

```
[
    {"id":114,"user_id":1,"customer_id":8,"pay_status":1,"pay_schedule":"weekly","types_supplied":"Pies","pay_period_start":"2017-05-01 00:00:00","pay_period_end":"2017-05-08 00:00:00","created_at":"2017-05-21 17:35:23","updated_at":"2017-05-21 17:35:23"}, 
    {"id":115,"user_id":1,"customer_id":8,"pay_status":1,"pay_schedule":"weekly","types_supplied":"Pies","pay_period_start":"2017-05-08 00:00:00","pay_period_end":"2017-05-15 00:00:00","created_at":"2017-05-21 17:35:23","updated_at":"2017-05-21 17:35:23"},
    {"id":116,"user_id":1,"customer_id":8,"pay_status":1,"pay_schedule":"weekly","types_supplied":"Pies","pay_period_start":"2017-05-15 00:00:00","pay_period_end":"2017-05-22 00:00:00","created_at":"2017-05-21 17:35:23","updated_at":"2017-05-21 17:35:23"},
    {"id":117,"user_id":1,"customer_id":8,"pay_status":1,"pay_schedule":"weekly","types_supplied":"Pies","pay_period_start":"2017-05-22 00:00:00","pay_period_end":"2017-05-29 00:00:00","created_at":"2017-05-21 17:35:23","updated_at":"2017-05-21 17:35:23"}
]
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please add some example data for the `$weeks` array, and the `$customer->payment`.

Comment: Sorry... I've added that now.

Comment: Is `$customer->payment` a Laravel Collection?

Comment: OP are you here ? so far what have you achieve in this ?

Comment: and can you have a sample desired output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

collections can be used to this ..

```
{{ $payments = collect($customer->payments) }}
@foreach($weeks as $week)
    {{ $filtered = $payments->where('pay_period_start ', $week['week_start'])->where('pay_period_end',$week['week_end']) }}
    @if(count($filtered) > 0)
        <div class="medium-3 columns">
            Week {{ $loop->iteration }}
            // also in this section .. you should have a relation from payment to status .. like payment belongsTo('App\status','pay_status');
            {{ $filtered->first()->status }}
        </div>
    @else
        // .. do your select here
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... with a little bit of adaptation your method worked. Thanks for your help.